# Upload to S3 from request.FILES Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Django and have a template with the following input field:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload">
```

When the form is submitted, I can access the submitted file like this:

```
request.FILES['file_upload']
```

Now that I have this file, **I want to upload it to my S3 bucket from the Python backend**. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? https://blog.theodo.com/2019/07/aws-s3-upload-django/

Comment: @MichaelHawkins From what I understand, the difference with my case is that I am not using ```models.FileField()``` and instead just want to upload directly from ```request.FILES```. Does this make sense?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use FileField or FilePathField? You don't want to store the file information in your database? How will you reference it?

Comment: @MichaelHawkins Just the way that my system design is set up (with JSON), it is easier to not use it. I will reference it using a unique id that will be stored in the JSON.

Comment: Ok, that's actually a lot harder. Why not just store it in a FileField and parse the FileField attributes that you want to JSON? You need to post that information in your answer.

Comment: @MichaelHawkins Sure, I will give that a shot, but I still think there is value in this question. Would you happen to know how to do it this way as well?